# scrape url with dd tags php

Tags: php, dom

i have to scrape a url and get the price of an item.
I'm trying simple php DOM, but there is something i'm doing wrong.
This is a portion of the code where the price is:

```
 <div class="Right">

                    <dl class="Price Offer" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                        <dt>Price:</dt>
                        <dd itemprop="price">$49.99</dd>
                        <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" content="In Stock"/>
                    </dl>

                    <dl class="Identifier">
                        <dt>Prod ID:</dt>
                        <dd itemprop="productID">68947</dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
```

I need to get the $49.99 and nothing else, but i'm really lost.
i've tried using ->plaintext and then doing some explode or str_replace but it seems i'm doing something wrong.

[This is the url i'm trying to scrape](http://www.buycostumes.com/Zombie-Hunter-Child-Costume/68947/ProductDetail.aspx)

Thanks!

Comment: $html =  file_get_html($url)->plaintext; started from there, implemented a function to strip tags, but it's not working on dd and dt tags.....

Comment: K, don't put it in a comment, put it in your post ..

Comment: I Did wrote it in the post, may be i should've do it as code... sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stupid and simple solution:

```
<?php
$scraptedText; //<-- your scraped site

$scraptedText = split('<dd itemprop="price">',$scraptedText);
$scraptedText = split('</dd>',  $scraptedText[1]);
$scraptedText = $scraptedText[0];
```

Im not really into regex, but this should work.